Direction of the polygonal curve in the Schwarz-Christoffel integral
I am reading section 4.2 of Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis, where the Schwarz-Christoffel integral is defined as
$$S(z)= \int_{0}^{z} \frac{d\zeta}{(\zeta-A_1)^{\beta_1}...(\zeta-A_n)^{\beta_n}}$$
where $A_1<...<A_n$ and $\beta_k<1$ for all $k$ and $1<\Sigma \beta_k\le2$. The powers are defined using the branch of log which is defined everywhere except the nonpositive imaginary axis. We define $a_k=S(A_k)$ for all $k$ and define $a_\infty=S(\infty)$.
In the proof that this integral maps $\mathbb{H}$ into the polygon with vertices $a_1,...,a_n,a_\infty$, they note that
$$S'(x)= \frac{1}{(x-A_1)^{\beta_1}...(x-A_n)^{\beta_n}}$$
is real and positive when $x>A_n$.
I believe this should mean that when $x$ travels from $A_n$ to $\infty$, $S(x)$ should travel in a straight line parallel to the real axis, from left to right. Hence $a_
n$ should be directly left of $a_\infty$.
However, the two drawings that are given in the book look like this (the first is when $\Sigma\beta_k=2$, so $a_1,a_\infty,a_n$ all lie on the same line).
In the picture, when $\Sigma\beta_k=2$, $a_1$ is to the left of $a_\infty$ which is to the left of $a_n$. But this seems backwards to me.
Even worse is the case when $\Sigma\beta_k<2$, when the line between $a_\infty$ and $a_n$ is not even horizontal.
As well, $a_\infty$ is depicted as being at the top in these images, but I believe it should really be at the bottom (ie: it should have a smaller imaginary component). Since the line between $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$ is at angle $-\pi\beta_n$ with the  real axis, hence it "points" downwards, so $a_{n-1}$ is above $a_n$.
So from my understanding, the polygon should have a flat bottom between points $a_n$ and $a_\infty$, where $a_n$ is to the left of $a_\infty$. And the rest of the points should be put counterclockwise around the polygon. But this is not what the picture in Stein and Shakarchi depicts, so I'm wondering if I have done something wrong.
Finally, this is only semi-related, but when I was trying to get a better understanding of this, I think I found another error in the text in example 4.3, where they calculate the integral
$$f(z)=\int_{0}^{z} \frac{d\zeta}{[(1-\zeta^2)(1-k^2\zeta^2)]^{1/2}}$$
where $0<k<1$.
However, $(1-\zeta^2)(1-k^2\zeta^2)$ takes on all possible arguments when $\zeta\in\mathbb{H}$ so it is impossible to define a branch of the logarithm such that $\log((1-\zeta^2)(1-k^2\zeta^2))$ is defined for all $\zeta\in\mathbb{H}$. I believe they incorrectly factored out the exponent of $1/2$, when it really should be
$$f(z)=\int_{0}^{z} \frac{d\zeta}{(1-\zeta^2)^{1/2}(1-k^2\zeta^2)^{1/2}}$$
Please let me know if my understanding is correct or if I have made a mistake somewhere. Thank you!
